# Declare variable in home profile file don't work

Tags: powershell

I have home profile file `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` in `C:\Users\User\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`. I want declare some variable, e.g `$A = 5`. When I start new powershell terminal and want display this variable ($A) result is empty (I don't see 5).

P.S.
If I put in this place other command, e.g. `Write-Host "Test text"` I see this when open new powershell terminal.

Somebody know why? :(

Comment: Can you show us the exact contents of your `$profile` script?

Comment: I have only `$A = 5`